# Why do i get a parser error while having a chat in any room

Tags: support, chat

[image]

I am getting this error quite common these days.In a chat room if I enter a message say 
hi.

I am getting as hi-parsererror -retry/cancel.
I don't understand why this error comes in the chat box.If I click on retry then the message is displayed in the room or else just the error. What could be the problem  exactly due to which this error appears.

Comment: Have you retried reloading the chat room (pressing F5)? If not, can you try and let me know if that fixes it?

Comment: @balpha refreshed helped but how do I avoid this error in future